# Simple array manipulation error?

Tags: c++

I'm currently teaching myself C++ and have run into a problem when trying to use arrays:

I'm trying to make a **tic-tac-toe** game, where the user will input two integers to announce where he would like to move, and then the board is printed out for them.

Except, when I try to modify my board once, it often will change two values!

**EXAMPLE)** if the first four numbers I input are `{0,1,1,0}` I would expect two letters to be drawn -- one "x" and one "o".

But instead multiple "o"s are drawn!

Thank you for the help!

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string board[2][2];
int xpos, ypos;
string turn;

int main()
{
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        board[i][j]="-";
    }

}
for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
{
    if(i%2==0)
        turn = "x";
    else
        turn = "o";

    cout<< "Where are you moving?\n";
    cin>> xpos >> ypos;

    board[xpos][ypos] = turn;

    cout<<"The board is:\n";
    cout<< board[0][0]+board[0][1]+board[0][2]+ "\n";
    cout<< board[1][0]+board[1][1]+board[1][2]+ "\n";
    cout<< board[2][0]+board[2][1]+board[2][2]+ "\n";

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're going out of bounds on your array. That's undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start change

```
string board[2][2];
```

to

```
string board[3][3];
```

As your loops are from 0 to 2 - i.e. 3 items

Comment: OH! The 2 in board[2][2] means 4 total items, not 9?

Comment: @user2899162 - Nowt is just not a Yorkshire thing - It is a number

Answer (score 0):

After changing the array from 2x2 to 3x3, I tested the code, and it seems to be working.

You should, however, check the values of `xpos` and `ypos` after user input: as the code is now,

```
board[xpos][ypos] = turn;
```

can be out of bounds, and can crash the program (if the user inputs anything bigger than 2 on any of the coordinates).

Finally, and this is a matter of personal preference, your code now uses user-entered coordinates from 0 to 2. Usually, people would say them in the range 1 to 3 (so 1,1 would be the top-left most square, not the middle one). Changing this is a matter of changing the previously quoted line to

```
board[xpos-1][ypos-1] = turn;
```

(After checking the values are between 1 and 3, of course).

*Edit:* Also, the coordinates, as asked, are vertical-horizontal (meaning the first value given represents the vertical coordinate and the second one represents the horizontal coordinate). So, on a standard cartesian graph, your values are being represented as (y,x), contrary to what people(and, I'm just guessing, you) are used to.